# Ajax reloading entire page on href link click

Tags: ajax, hyperlink, click, href, reload

I have a website built in ajax. It has both English and French versions. English is at /public_html and french in /public_html/fr.

Ajax is only reloading the middle frame and not the header or footer. So, when I click the link to the French page, it shows it in the middle, but the header and footer are still from the English page.

So, basically a "#" is coming from nowhere when I click the link: eg. http://www.mysite.com/index.html#http://www.mysite.com/fr/index.html

English to French:

```
<li class="contact"><a href="/fr/index.html">French Version</a></li>
```

French to English:

```
<li class="contact"><a href="/index.html">English Version</a></li>
```

I need that, on click, the entire page is reloaded. What should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: This question doesn't make a lot of sense. Ajax... how? Using a framework? What's the structure of your site?

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a stab. It sounds like you're describing a framed site with a non-ajax hyperlink in the middle of it. The link is "refreshing" the middle frame because that's where the link is.  You can add a `target` to the anchor tag to tell it to reload the whole page.

```
<a href="/fr/index.html" target="_top">French Version</a>
```

PS While you're at it, don't forget to localize the words "French Version" (*Version française*? :-)

Comment: So what's hijacking the link?